# Build server on Premises and vso basic users

Tags: build, licensing, azure-devops

In my company I have created a VSO account with 11 msdn subscription users and 5 basic.
If I setup a local build server do I need CAL on he server for these basic Users? Or simply they wont be able to run a build?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need a CAL for setting up a build server on premises for use with VSO users, including Basic.